# Tree View in React-Native

Tags: javascript, react-native

I need to do Tree view in React-native. I checked with `react-native-final-tree-view`. But here we can't have the child click event. Also, I tried with `react-native-drillable-object-view`, but I need exact behaviour of like this https://reactjsexample.com/a-simple-react-tree-menu-component.

Under this library, they used Typescript to react. Is it possible to do the same behaviour in `react-native` without using typescript?

If any once know please let me know. I am new in react-native and react.

Comment: Have you tried implementing it yourself? Making a treeview in react is a very fun and cool task to do. You should try implementing your self, is not that hard.

Comment: You can literally take the example written in TypeScript and write in in JavaScript?

Comment: Hi,  i had some changes in react-native-final-tree-view. Now its working what i have expected. thanks